# Exact Duplicate records in Ms Access DB Deleting?

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a database which imports linked data-tables. Obviously with linked Tables I cannot change the design of the data tables. However there are many duplicates in the data table that I want to use and my aim is to run a query that deletes all but 1 of the duplicates in the table. Is there a way of doing this??

Any support would be appreciated.

Chris

Answer (score 1):

To omit the duplicates you could conceivably create a SELECT DISTINCT query to return all the fields from the linked table, and then use that query (instead of the linked table) as a basis for your other queries.